# Angular 2 main.js not found 404 error

Tags: angular

I have created an angular 2 app and it was running fine, but when i changed the path of main.js(which was created from main.ts) file from ./ to ./app  and i changed that in systemjs.config.js also as below

```
packages: {
      app: {
        main: './app/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
```

But still am getting 404 file not foundfor main.js while loading the app. Is there any othere chage we need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the structure of your components to see where could be the error. 
I recommend you to use [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) to start your project with a correct structure.

Comment: Please find below the structure of the project, all the component files are under the app folder,

Answer (score 0):

The following plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/4fT2ahOC3o61FEB4jVSK?p=preview is changes the ts format to js in your systemjs.config.js.

```
 packages: {
      '.': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
```